# We have a web application which uses CRON4J scheduling. The Jobs are running twice for same scheduling time. can anybody know why?

Tags: java, tomcat, cron4j

We have a web application which uses CRON4J scheduling. The Jobs are running twice for same scheduling time. can anybody know why?
we deployed this app on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely registering the `Task` twice. May be there is another copy of your `war` deployed, so you actually have **2** instances of your application running ?

Answer (score 0):

If you scheduler is defined in the context listener, check how many times have you defined the context. It will be executed for each context .
You can have multiple context if you use virtual host, or if you define one context in the war (META-INF/context.xml) and other in server.xml (you should not define context here).